# How to reliably call immediate parent's virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding, virtual

Consider this code

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void print ()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::print" << std::endl;
    }
};

class BaseA : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void print ()
    {
        std::cout << "BaseA::print" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void print ()
    {
        Base::print (); // <= this will always call Base::print even if I derive from BaseA
        std::cout << "Derived::print" << std::endl;
    }

};


int main ()
{
    Base* a = new Derived;
    a->print ();
    delete a;
}
```

From `Derived::print` I call `Base::print` which is fine untill I deside to derive my `Derived` from `BaseA` instead, whereupon I want of course to call `BaseA::print`. Changing `Base::print` to `BaseA::print` in this particular example is not a problem, but what if I have 20 such virtual functions?

How to ask compiler to call immediate parent's version of the `print` whatever that is?

Comment: I have noticed an increase in frequency in questions about virtual methods.

Comment: @Mark Garcia: Must be an evil conspiracy.  We shouldn't contribute answers -- "*they*" will only grow stronger. (Seriously, if this is a duplicate, which it may be, flag it as such, and cite the original.) :)

Comment: @DavidO There must be someone behind all of this.

Comment: I think you have a problem. You believe that you will *always* want to call the immediate base class' virtual function, even though you right now don't know what the base class will be. My crystal ball says that you will actually only want to do this for 18 of the 20 virtuals, and that this solution just gives you a new problem instead. When changing an inheritance structure, you just *have to* re-evaluate everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a typedef:

```
class Derived: public BaseA {
    typedef BaseA Base;
    ...
```

Compile-time introspection of a class's immediate bases is not currently possible, although there are proposals (e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3326.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You could try with templates:

```
template <class base>
class test: public base
{
    virtual void testmethod()
    {
        base::testmethod();
    }
};
```

Then you could add a typedef:

```
typedef test<myBaseClass> myDerivedClass;
```